# Log column constraint violations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a column constraint on a very large table to make sure that no inserted or updated data can record stock levels of zero or below. Occasionally our applications report an error because these constraints are being violated.

Is there any way to write the row of data to a table or log file if a constraint violation is made?

Comment: Not out of the box, I think. You could always build a trigger.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, There is no need to create explicit trigger if check constraint is already built at the time of table definition.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai If that's the case you can add an answer to describe how to log the violation.

Comment: I am not saying that we can log the violation. I am saying if check constraint is already on place at the time of table definition, there would be no violation.

Comment: I have considered tracing violations to the error log, but don't know how to send the row anywhere.

Comment: You can create a stored proc for the same. Just check if data is safe enough to insert into the table then insert it otherwise if it violating your table definition, send this to another table named as error_records or like something.

Comment: You could always have your insert be in a stored proc (hopefully it is anyway). Then simply wrap the insert in a try/catch and log the attempted insert values in the catch block.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai How would I start it off when there is a constraint violation? What is the event?

Comment: you can use a variable and set it to 1 if row inserted successfully into your first table if it is still 0 then the row did not inserted into you r first table and insert it into your error_log table.

Comment: @SeanLange The application writes to tables directly. It is a huge system and we are unable to change higher processes or data structures. I have the violation and have to work from there.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I cannot change the system that writes to the table. I have to work with the constraint violation.

Comment: Then you must create a trigger and delete the violated record form the table after each and every insert.

Comment: You would have to setup an extended event to capture violations or create instead of triggers on your tables using the try/catch scenario I described earlier.

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016003/capture-primary-key-constraint-violation-in-sql-server-2008), but I doubt they'll help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to put a BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE trigger on the table.

In the trigger, check the `inserted` table to see if any rows would violate the constraint, and if so, write them to your Log table instead of the destination table.

Any rows that don't violate the constraint are then written to the destination table.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't a before trigger in sql server, you would have to use an instead of trigger.

Comment: Yes. I see I am pushed into a trigger solution. The INSTEAD of trigger use a  TRY...CATCH to see if insertions or updates return the error number for constraint violation. If they do, write to a table, if not, just go ahead with the data change. 
Thanks for the advice, everyone.